# Getting innerHTML from object via jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

I have a problem with getting `innerHTML` from object that looks like this:

```
<a class="trackable-user" href="/blame.fic">
    <i class="icon-user"></i>
    #BlameFic
</a>
```

Got this object by typing `$("ul#userDropDown li:eq(2) a")`. So my question is what do I need to add to my selector to get **#BlameFic** from the object that I mentioned.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the `text`

```
$("ul#userDropDown li:eq(2) a").text();
```

Comment: Thx for the fast answer, first day of my JS journey so I'm still confused :D

Answer (score 1):

What tymeJV is correct. Use text() to get the value. Here is just another variation:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var track = $("a.trackable-user").text();

});
</script>
```